# How to set top padding of Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application, I need to set a top padding for Entry control in iOS. I created renderers for Entry , but only I am able to set Left and Right padding. Please help me. Following is the my Entry Renderer

```
public class CustomRenderer: EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        if (Control != null) {
            Control.LeftView = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 0, 15, 0));
            Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, you could avoid using renderer. You could try to use `Margin` for `Entry`. Second thing is, maybe, your `Entry` has no free space at the top, so it couldn't add this indent. Could you add code, how you locate your `Entry`?

Comment: Use margin property `<Entry Margin="left, top, right, bottom"/>` so e.g. `Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"`

Comment: I need to set padding for the text inside the Entry , so can't use margin

Comment: @Aneesh.A.M Did you figure it out? I believe you can use Control.SetPadding()

Comment: Hi Aneesh! Let me know if my answer below helps! If you don't have any follow up questions, let's mark this question as Answered to help fellow developers in the future when they have a similar question!

Answer (score 7):

## To accomplish this, we need to do two things:

1. Increase the height of the `Entry` in Xamarin.Forms
2. Create an iOS Custom Renderer to align the text to the bottom of the `UITextField` 
   [image]

## Increase The Entry Height in Xamarin.Forms

In this example, I use a `RelativeLayout` to set the height of the Padded Entry to 50, `Constraint.Constant(50)`.

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomEntrySample
{
    public class EntryWithTopPadding : Entry
    {
    }

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var normalEntry = new Entry
            {
                Text = "This Entry Has Normal Padding",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Lime
            };

            var paddedEntry = new EntryWithTopPadding
            {
                Text = "This Entry Has Extra Top Padding",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua
            };

            var mainLayout = new RelativeLayout();
            mainLayout.Children.Add(
                normalEntry,
                Constraint.Constant(0),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Y + 10),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width)
            );
            mainLayout.Children.Add(
                paddedEntry,
                Constraint.Constant(0),
                Constraint.RelativeToView(normalEntry, (parent, view) => view.Y + view.Height + 10),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width),
                Constraint.Constant(50)
            );

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(
                new ContentPage
                {
                    Title = "Title",
                    Content = mainLayout,
                    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0)
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

## Create Custom Renderer to Align Text to the Bottom of UITextField

Set the `VerticalAlignment` property of the `UITextField` to `UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Bottom`

```
using UIKit;

using CustomEntrySample;
using CustomEntrySample.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryWithTopPadding), typeof(EntryWithTopPaddingCustomRenderer))]
namespace CustomEntrySample.iOS
{
    public class EntryWithTopPaddingCustomRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control == null)
                return;

            Control.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this for setting padding to an entry cell:

Padding in IOS :

```
Control.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0,15,0,0));
Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
Control.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0,10, 0, 0));
Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

Padding in Android:

```
Control.SetPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Accordingly, you can set the value to make text start from specific position.